# Translating "since" or "because" into Spanish

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

I almost always go with **porque** but I have come across several different translations some of which are:

> **ya que**
>
> **desde que**
>
> **para que**
>
> **pues**

How do these translations differ in nuance and how does one pick the best one for a given scenario? And if, by any chance, they do happen to be absolutely synonymous, is there any usage preference, dialectical or otherwise?

I am only interested in the context of "because" or "since." For example, I understand that **pues** can mean a bunch of other things like *well*, *alright*, etc. too but I am not talking about those interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending the context, you can translate since as "desde", "ya que", "debido a" and "porque"

On the other hand, you can translate because as "porque"

You can use both words in same sentences:
Compró pan, porque se le había acabado.
Compró pan, ya que se le había acabado.
Compró pan, debido a que se le había acabado.

In most of sentences, common language people use "because". In other words: kids allways use "porque", never "since".

Other important thing is you can't start a sentnce using "porque" if it's not answering a question. you can't said: "porque tenía hambre, compré pan". However you can said "ya que tenía hambre, compré pan"

Comment: **Since** doesn't always mean *from*, or a time in the past. It also means *because* and that's the interpretation my question refers to. An illustration: "I did it since nobody else would."

Comment: In spanish I think its different. Nobody will translate your sentence as "desde que nadie", but "porque nadie". Just my opinion

Comment: What about **ya que**, **para que**, and **pues**? The question seeks a clarification on how one decides on which one to use as a translation for *because* or *since* (in the sense of *because*). With examples illustrating their differences. Your answer does none. You might want to expand your response to cover the subject better?

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope any other could answer better your question.

Comment: _Ya que_, _pues_, _puesto que_ and _dado que_ can all be used as substitutes of _porque_. It is more or less the same diference there is in English between _because_ and _given that_ (which is the exact translation of _dado que_). _Para que_, which I guess is a mistranslation of _for_, does not mean _because_ in Spanish — it means purpose, not consequence.